# Puma compiled without SSL support (RuntimeError) Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I want to start Puma (v.5.2.2) using SSL in on Windows on Rails 6.

When I execute:

```
bundle exec puma
```

I get the following error:

```
Puma compiled without SSL support (RuntimeError)
```

I have openssl installed:

```
>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
```

In the file puma.rb, I inserted:

```
ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', 3000, {
  key: 'mykey.key',
  cert: 'mykey.crt',
  verify_mode: 'none'
}
```

I generated mykey.key and mykey.crt and put them in Rails root folder.

What I've already tried, without success:

- I reinstalled Puma after the installation of openssl
- I ran the server using this command: `rails s -b "ssl://localhost:3000?key=mykey.key&cert=mykey.crt"`
- I tried Puma version 4.x.x

Comment: Take a look at this issue https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/971#issuecomment-751391934

Answer (score 2):

```
> ruby -rpuma -e "puts Puma.ssl?"
false
```

```
gem install puma
```

```
> ruby -rpuma -e "puts Puma.ssl?"
true
```